# android browser downloadfile.bin (wordpress cf7)

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, android-browser

i got a little problem with a wordpress site that uses contact form 7 and android browser (at least android v1.5).

when a user submits the cf7 form (using ajax followed by a js redirect) and tries to return to the forms page later (using the back button as well as opening the form's url) the download prompt for a 'downloadfile.bin' appears.

this behavior can not be reproduced on any other mobile or desktop browsers.

could anyone shed some light on this issue?

thank you in advance!

Comment: I've experienced this when I was just browsing the internet, no form submissions or anything.. Don't know what it is unfortunately..